Solving the 2D Helmholtz Equation over a sphere with a PINN
Background: I am working on implementing solutions to various partial differential equations through Physics-informed neural networks (PINNs). I have started working on the Helmholtz equation and was able to use a PINN to approximate the solution in a square. However, generalizing this code to a circle doesn't appear to work. I'm not sure why my generalization from a square to a circle doesn't work.
Helmholtz 2D Circle PINN Information: I am looking to solve the 2D Helmholtz boundary value problem
$$\begin{cases}
 \Delta u + k^2 u = 0, &~\text{in} ~\Omega \\
 u(x)=g(x), &~\text{on}~\partial\Omega
 \end{cases}$$
where $x=(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb R^2$, $~\Omega\subset\mathbb R^2$ is bounded, $g$ is bounded, and $k$ is the wave number.  In this problem, $\Delta u$ represents the Laplacian operator, which in 2D is given by
$$ \Delta u = \Delta u(x_1,x_2) = \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x_1^2} + \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x_2^2}.$$
I would like to solve for $u(x)$ within the domain $\Omega$ subject to the boundary condition $u(x) = g(x)$ on $\partial \Omega$. To numerically solve this problem, I discretize the domain $\Omega$ into a 2D grid of points using boundary points at the edges and collocation points within the domain.
As $\Omega$ is a sphere of radius $\pi$, I convert into polar coordinates and the Laplacian becomes
$$
\Delta u =  \Delta u(r,\theta) = \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} + \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial \theta^2} 
$$
where $r$ is the radius of the sphere and $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$. I believe that an analytical solution (one of many) to the Helmholtz equation in a circular domain is given by
$$u(r,\theta) = J_n(k r) \cos(n\theta)$$
where $J_n$ is a Bessel function of the first kind and $n$ is the mode number. This implies that my Helmholtz PINN should minimize

The data loss, which penalizes deviation from the boundary conditions.
The physics loss, which ensures that the solution satisfies the Helmholtz equation (i.e., minimizing the PDE residual) inside the domain.

Given that my source term is
$$q(r,\theta) = k^2 J_n(k r) \cos(n\theta)$$
the PDE residual $R(r,\theta)$ becomes
$$R(r,\theta)=\Delta u+k^2u-q(r,\theta)=\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} + \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial \theta^2} + k^2u - k^2 J_n(k r) \cos(n\theta).$$
With these, my 2D Helmholtz PINN Python implementation over a circle is:
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.autograd import grad
import os
from scipy.special import j0, jn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Set default data type and random seeds
torch.set_default_dtype(torch.float32)
torch.manual_seed(1234)
np.random.seed(1234)

# Use GPU if available
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')


class HelmholtzPINN(nn.Module):
    """
    PINN for solving the 2D Helmholtz equation in a circular domain.

    Parameters
    ----------
    layers : list of int
        A list defining the number of nodes in each layer of the network.
    """

    def __init__(self, layers):
        super().__init__()
        self.activation = nn.Tanh()
        self.loss_function = nn.MSELoss()
        self.linears = nn.ModuleList([nn.Linear(layers[i], layers[i + 1]) for i in range(len(layers) - 1)])

        # Xavier normal initialization for weights
        for linear in self.linears:
            nn.init.xavier_normal_(linear.weight)
            nn.init.zeros_(linear.bias)

    def forward(self, x):
        """
        Forward pass through the network.

        Parameters
        ----------
        x : torch.Tensor
            Input tensor of shape (N, 2), where N is the number of points.

        Returns
        -------
        torch.Tensor
            Output tensor of shape (N, 1).
        """
        for i, linear in enumerate(self.linears[:-1]):
            x = self.activation(linear(x))
        return self.linears[-1](x)

    def loss_pde(self, x_f, n, k):
        """
        Computes the PDE loss (residual of the 2D Helmholtz equation) using automatic differentiation to calculate
        second-order derivatives.

        Parameters
        ----------
        x_f : torch.Tensor
            Collocation points for PDE training.
        n : int
            Mode number for the Bessel function of the first kind.
        k : float
            Wave number for the Helmholtz equation.

        Returns
        -------
        torch.Tensor
            PDE loss.
        """
        g = x_f.clone().requires_grad_(True)  # Ensure gradients can be computed for x_f
        u = self.forward(g)  # Forward pass to get predicted u at collocation points

        # Convert to polar coordinates
        r = torch.sqrt(g[:, 0] ** 2 + g[:, 1] ** 2)  # Radius r = sqrt(x^2 + y^2)
        theta = torch.atan2(g[:, 1], g[:, 0])  # Angle theta = atan2(y, x)

        # First derivatives of u with respect to x and y
        u_x = grad(u, g, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(u), create_graph=True)[0][:, 0]
        u_y = grad(u, g, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(u), create_graph=True)[0][:, 1]

        # First derivatives of u with respect to r and theta using chain rule
        u_r = u_x * torch.cos(theta) + u_y * torch.sin(theta)
        u_theta = -u_x * torch.sin(theta) + u_y * torch.cos(theta)

        # Second derivatives of u with respect to x and y
        u_xx = grad(u_x, g, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(u_x), create_graph=True)[0][:, 0]
        u_yy = grad(u_y, g, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(u_y), create_graph=True)[0][:, 1]

        # Second derivatives of u with respect to r and theta
        u_rr = u_xx * torch.cos(theta) ** 2 + u_yy * torch.sin(theta) ** 2
        u_thetatheta = grad(u_theta, theta, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(u_theta), create_graph=True)[0] / r

        # Laplacian in polar coordinates
        laplacian_u = u_rr + (1 / r) * u_r + (1 / r ** 2) * u_thetatheta

        # Source term
        q = k ** 2 * torch.special.bessel_j0(k * r) * torch.cos(n * theta)

        # PDE residual: Laplacian(u) + k^2 * u - q
        residual = laplacian_u + k ** 2 * u - q

        # Return the mean squared error between the residual and zero
        return self.loss_function(residual, torch.zeros_like(residual))

    def loss_data(self, x_u, u_true):
        """
        Computes the boundary data loss (MSE between true and predicted boundary values).

        Parameters
        ----------
        x_u : torch.Tensor
            Boundary condition points.
        u_true : torch.Tensor
            True solution values at boundary points.

        Returns
        -------
        torch.Tensor
            Data loss.
        """
        u_pred = self.forward(x_u)
        return self.loss_function(u_pred, u_true)

    def compute_loss(self, x_f, x_u, u_true, n, k):
        """
        Computes the total loss as the sum of PDE loss and data loss.

        Parameters
        ----------
        x_f : torch.Tensor
            Collocation points.
        x_u : torch.Tensor
            Boundary condition points.
        u_true : torch.Tensor
            True boundary values.
        n : int
            Mode number.
        k : float
            Wave number.

        Returns
        -------
        torch.Tensor
            Total loss.
        """
        pde_loss = self.loss_pde(x_f, n, k)
        data_loss = self.loss_data(x_u, u_true)
        return pde_loss + data_loss


def create_circle_grid(num_points=256, radius=np.pi):
    """
    Create a 2D grid of points inside a circle of radius pi.

    Parameters
    ----------
    num_points : int
        Number of points to generate.
    radius : float
        Radius of the circle.

    Returns
    -------
    X : np.ndarray
        Grid points in the x-dimension.
    Y : np.ndarray
        Grid points in the y-dimension.
    mask : np.ndarray
        Mask indicating points inside the circle.
    """
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, num_points)
    r = np.linspace(0, radius, num_points)
    R, Theta = np.meshgrid(r, theta)
    X = R * np.cos(Theta)
    Y = R * np.sin(Theta)

    # Filter points inside the circle (r <= radius)
    mask = R <= radius
    return X[mask], Y[mask]


def prepare_circle_training_data(N_u, N_f, radius, usol):
    """
    Prepare boundary and collocation points for a circular domain.

    Parameters
    ----------
    N_u : int
        Number of boundary points.
    N_f : int
        Number of collocation points.
    radius : float
        Radius of the circle.
    usol : np.ndarray
        Analytical solution at grid points.

    Returns
    -------
    X_f_train : np.ndarray
        Collocation points.
    X_u_train : np.ndarray
        Boundary points.
    u_train : np.ndarray
        Boundary values.
    """
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, N_u)
    X_u_train = np.column_stack([radius * np.cos(theta), radius * np.sin(theta)])  # Boundary points on the circle
    u_train = usol(X_u_train[:, 0], X_u_train[:, 1]).reshape(-1, 1)  # Boundary values

    # Collocation points inside the circle
    X_f_train = np.random.uniform(-radius, radius, (N_f, 2))
    mask = np.linalg.norm(X_f_train, axis=1) <= radius
    X_f_train = X_f_train[mask]

    return X_f_train, X_u_train, u_train


def usol(x, y, n=1, k=np.sqrt(2) * np.pi):
    """
    Analytical solution for the Helmholtz equation inside a circular domain through the Bessel function.

    Parameters
    ----------
    x, y : float
        Coordinates.
    k : float
        Wavenumber.

    Returns
    -------
    u : float
        Analytical solution value.
    """
    r = np.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2)
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, len(x))
    return j0(k * r) * np.cos(n * theta)


def plot_solution(u_pred, usol, X, Y, epoch, figures_dir, radius=np.pi):
    """
    Plot the predicted solution, analytical solution, and absolute error inside a circular domain.

    Parameters
    ----------
    u_pred : np.ndarray
        Predicted solution from the model.
    usol : np.ndarray
        Analytical solution.
    X, Y : np.ndarray
        Grids of x and y points.
    epoch : int
        Current training epoch.
    figures_dir : str
        Directory where the figures will be saved.
    radius : float
        Radius of the circular domain.
    """
    r = np.sqrt(X ** 2 + Y ** 2)
    mask = r <= radius  # Only points inside the circle

    abs_error = np.abs(usol - u_pred)

    plt.figure(figsize=(18, 5))

    # Analytical solution (mask points outside the circle)
    plt.subplot(1, 3, 1)
    plt.scatter(X[mask], Y[mask], c=usol[mask], cmap='jet', s=1)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.title('Analytical Solution')

    # Predicted solution
    plt.subplot(1, 3, 2)
    plt.scatter(X[mask], Y[mask], c=u_pred[mask], cmap='jet', s=1)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.title(f'Predicted Solution at Epoch {epoch}')

    # Absolute error
    plt.subplot(1, 3, 3)
    plt.scatter(X[mask], Y[mask], c=abs_error[mask], cmap='jet', s=1)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.title('Absolute Error')

    plt.tight_layout()

    # Create the directory if it doesn't exist
    os.makedirs(figures_dir, exist_ok=True)

    # Save the figure in the specified directory
    figure_path = os.path.join(figures_dir, f'Helmholtz_circle_iter_{epoch}.png')
    plt.savefig(figure_path, dpi=500, bbox_inches='tight')

    plt.show()
    plt.pause(0.1)


def plot_training_domain(X_f_train, X_u_train, radius=np.pi):
    """
    Visualizes the boundary points and collocation points on a circular domain.

    Parameters
    ----------
    X_f_train : np.ndarray
        Collocation points to visualize.
    X_u_train : np.ndarray
        Boundary points to visualize.
    radius : float
        Radius of the circular domain.
    """
    plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))

    # Plot boundary points (red)
    plt.scatter(X_u_train[:, 0], X_u_train[:, 1], color='red', label='Boundary Points', alpha=0.6)

    # Plot collocation points (blue)
    plt.scatter(X_f_train[:, 0], X_f_train[:, 1], color='blue', label='Collocation Points', alpha=0.3)

    # Plot the circle
    circle = plt.Circle((0, 0), radius, color='green', fill=False, label=f'Circle with radius {radius}')
    plt.gca().add_artist(circle)

    plt.xlim([-radius, radius])
    plt.ylim([-radius, radius])
    plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
    plt.xlabel('$x$', fontsize=14)
    plt.ylabel('$y$', fontsize=14)
    plt.title('Boundary and Collocation Points for Training')
    plt.legend()
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()


def plot_training_progress(train_losses, test_losses, train_maes, test_maes, steps, figDir):
    """
    Plot the training and test losses, along with the train and test MAEs, over the course of training.

    Parameters
    ----------
    train_losses : list
        List of training loss values recorded at each training step.
    test_losses : list
        List of test loss values recorded at each evaluation step.
    train_maes : list
        List of train MAE values recorded during training.
    test_maes : list
        List of test MAE values recorded during training.
    steps : list
        List of step numbers corresponding to the recorded losses and metrics.
    figDir : str
        Directory where the figures will be saved.

    Returns
    -------
    None
    """
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))

    # Plot training loss
    plt.plot(steps, train_losses, label='Train Loss (MSE)', color='blue', linestyle='-', marker='o')

    # Plot test loss
    plt.plot(steps, test_losses, label='Test Loss (MSE)', color='red', linestyle='--', marker='x')

    # Plot train MAE
    plt.plot(steps, train_maes, label='Train MAE', color='green', linestyle='-.', marker='s')

    # Plot test MAE
    plt.plot(steps, test_maes, label='Test MAE', color='orange', linestyle=':', marker='d')

    plt.xlabel('Steps', fontsize="x-large")
    plt.ylabel('MSE / MAE', fontsize="x-large")
    plt.legend()
    plt.title('Training Progress: MSE and MAE')

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.yscale('log')

    # Create the directory if it doesn't exist
    os.makedirs(figures_dir, exist_ok=True)

    # Save the figure in the specified directory
    figure_path = os.path.join(figures_dir, f'Helmholtz_Training_Progress_Circle.png')
    plt.savefig(figure_path, dpi=500, bbox_inches='tight')

    plt.savefig('training_progress.png', dpi=500, bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.show()
    plt.pause(0.1)


def train_pinn(N_u=500, N_f=10000, layers=[2, 200, 200, 200, 1], epochs=1000, lr=0.01, figDir=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Helmholtz_Figures")):
    """
    Train the Physics-Informed Neural Network for the Helmholtz equation.

    Parameters
    ----------
    N_u : int
        Number of boundary points.
    N_f : int
        Number of collocation points.
    layers : list of int
        Network architecture.
    epochs : int
        Number of training epochs.
    lr : float
        Learning rate.
    figDir : str
        Directory where the figures will be saved.

    Returns
    -------
    HelmholtzPINN
        Trained model.
    """
    # Generate grid and exact solution
    X, Y = create_circle_grid()
    usol_vals = usol(X, Y)
    radius = np.pi

    # Prepare training data
    X_f_train, X_u_train, u_train = prepare_circle_training_data(N_u, N_f, radius, usol)

    # Split the boundary data into 80% training and 20% testing
    split_idx = int(0.8 * X_u_train.shape[0])
    X_u_train_split = X_u_train[:split_idx]
    u_train_split = u_train[:split_idx]
    X_u_test = X_u_train[split_idx:]
    u_test = u_train[split_idx:]

    # Convert to tensors
    X_f_train = torch.tensor(X_f_train, dtype=torch.float32).to(device)
    X_u_train = torch.tensor(X_u_train, dtype=torch.float32).to(device)
    X_u_train_split = torch.tensor(X_u_train_split, dtype=torch.float32).to(device)
    u_train_split = torch.tensor(u_train_split, dtype=torch.float32).to(device)
    X_u_test = torch.tensor(X_u_test, dtype=torch.float32).to(device)
    u_test = torch.tensor(u_test, dtype=torch.float32).to(device)

    # Visualize the training domain
    plot_training_domain(X_f_train.cpu().numpy(), X_u_train.cpu().numpy(), radius)

    # Create model
    model = HelmholtzPINN(layers).to(device)
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)

    # Store training progress
    train_losses = []
    test_losses = []
    train_maes = []
    test_maes = []
    steps = []

    for epoch in range(epochs):
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # Compute train loss
        loss = model.compute_loss(X_f_train, X_u_train_split, u_train_split, n=1, k=np.sqrt(2) * np.pi)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        # Record training loss and MAE
        train_loss = loss.item()
        u_pred_train = model(X_u_train_split)
        train_mae = nn.L1Loss()(u_pred_train, u_train_split).item()

        # Test the model on test data every 10 epochs
        if epoch % 10 == 0:
            with torch.no_grad():
                u_pred_test = model(X_u_test)
                test_loss = model.loss_data(X_u_test, u_test).item()  # Test loss (MSE)
                test_mae = nn.L1Loss()(u_pred_test, u_test).item()  # Test MAE

                # Store values for plotting
                steps.append(epoch)
                train_losses.append(train_loss)
                test_losses.append(test_loss)
                train_maes.append(train_mae)
                test_maes.append(test_mae)

        # Print every 400 epochs
        if epoch % 400 == 0:
            print(f'Epoch {epoch}/{epochs}, Train Loss: {train_loss:.6f}, Train MAE: {train_mae:.6f}',
                  f'Test Loss: {test_loss:.6f}, Test MAE: {test_mae:.6f}')

            # Predict solution
            u_pred = model(torch.tensor(np.column_stack((X.flatten(), Y.flatten())), dtype=torch.float32).to(device))
            u_pred = u_pred.cpu().detach().numpy().reshape(X.shape)

            # Plot analytical, predicted solution, and absolute error
            plot_solution(u_pred, usol_vals, X, Y, epoch, figDir)

    # Plot the training/test loss and mae over time
    plot_training_progress(train_losses, test_losses, train_maes, test_maes, steps, figDir)

    return model


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Network Parameters
    N_u = 500  # Number of boundary points
    N_f = 10000  # Number of collocation points
    layers = [2, 20, 20, 20, 1]  # Neural network architecture
    epochs = 1001  # Number of training epochs
    lr = 0.01 # Learning rate

    # Create figures directory if it doesn't exist
    figures_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Helmholtz_Figures")
    os.makedirs(figures_dir, exist_ok=True)

    # Train the PINN
    model = train_pinn(N_u=N_u, N_f=N_f, layers=layers, epochs=epochs, lr=lr, figDir=figures_dir)


The training domain in my Python implementation is

and I can immediately see that something might be wrong with the way the PDE loss is calculated as the predicted solution doesn't match the analytical solution as training progresses.

Question: Assuming that PINNs work equally well in both cartesian/polar coordinates, it must be that something is wrong with my residual (or analytical solution) in polar coordinates. I have tried several different varients of the PDE residual inside a circle and nothing seems to converge. This seems odd to me as the training procedure of the PINN should minimize the PDE loss (residual) and converge to the analytical solution in both domains.
